# How do I get an Android emulator running API 14 (or API 15)?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to quickly smoke test my soon to be released Android app update as functional on API 14 and/or 15. Previously to test on Ice Cream Sandwich, I had a physical device to validate my code on, but I don't have it anymore.

I'm building with a recent install of the Eclipse/ADT tools. I had thought that older emulator images were available from the SDK Manager.  Instead, it only appears that I can install the build tools from previous SDK releases, but not the corresponding system images for the emulator. (I've got "obsolete" packages checkbox set as well - still nothing).  The AVD editor continues to show "no system images present" when the the Target setting is API 14.

How do I get download emulator (AVD or otherwise) to run an Ice Cream Sandwhich build?

[image]

Comment: In the SDK Manager, go to Tools > Options in the menu and click "Clear Cache". Then choose Packages > Reload from the SDK Manager menu. See if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I tried that.  No luck.

Comment: Is your "Android SDK Tools" and "Android SDK Platform-tools" up to date? They should be towards the top of the Tools folder in SDK Manager. Sometimes things get filtered out of the SDK Manager because they depend upon newer editions of those items than what you have.

Comment: @CommonsWare I checked Genymotion. They do not have any ICS device either.

Comment: @LittleChild: The OP is referring to the standard Android SDK emulator. The SDK Manager has the entries that the OP needs, at least on my machine. The question is why the SDK Manager is not showing those entries on the OP's machine.

Comment: @CommonsWare - it might have been something along the lines of what are were suggesting. Basically, it was just easier to go download Eclipse/ADT bundle again and install clean. And now all is good. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short summary: Did a clean install of Android/ADT/Eclipse tools and all is well.

Basically did this.  Removed the directory Eclipse/ADT was installed in.  Then removed my ".android" folder (on windows this is located in my c:\users\ directory).

Then I downloaded the ADT/Eclipse bundle again. After that, I was able to get the older emulator images through "SDK Manager" again.